# Calculating the % of comment text in a file

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of comment text in a file but I can't figure out what's wrong with my calculation method.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int k, commNum1 = 0, commNum2 = 0, Nbrackets1 = 0, Nbrackets2 = 0, Cbrackets1 = 0, Cbrackets2 = 0, tabs = 0, spaces = 0;
    char str[10000];
    char ch, file_name[75];
    FILE *fp;
    char writtenText[2000];

    printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see with extension .c or .txt\n");
    gets(file_name);

    fp = fopen(file_name, "a");  // reads the file

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        _getche();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
    gets(writtenText);
    fprintf(fp, "%s", writtenText);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    printf("The contents of %s file are :\n\n", file_name);
    int i = 0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        //      printf("%c", ch);
        str[i] = ch;                                        //printing and storing process
        i++;
    }
    int fsize = i;

    for (k = 0; k < fsize; k++) {
        if (str[k] == '(')
            Nbrackets1++;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < fsize; k++) {
        if (str[k] == ')')
            Nbrackets2++;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < fsize; k++) {
        if (str[k] == '{')
            Cbrackets1++;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < fsize; k++) {
        if (str[k] == '}')
            Cbrackets2++;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < fsize; k++) {
        if (str[k] == '\t')
            tabs++;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < fsize; k++) {
        if (str[k] == ' ')
            spaces++;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < fsize; k++) {
        if (str[k] == '/' && str[k + 1] == '*') {
            while (str[k] != '*' && str[k + 1] != '/') {
                commNum1++;
                if (str[k] == ' ') {
                    commNum1--;
                }
                //              printf("commNum1 = %d\n",commNum1);                 //just to test if my calculations are correct
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (k = 0; k < fsize; k++) {
        if (str[k] == '/' && str[k + 1] == '/') {
            while (str[k] != '\n') {
                commNum2++;
                if (str[k] == ' ') {
                    commNum2--;
                }
                //              printf("commNum2 = %d\n",commNum2);                 //just to test if my calculations are correct
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    double commAVG = (commNum1 + commNum2) / fsize * 100;
    double avgTAS = (tabs + spaces) / 2;
    printf("\n\nOccurence of character ( : %d", Nbrackets1);
    printf("\nOccurence of character ) : %d", Nbrackets2);
    printf("\nOccurence of character {  : %d ", Cbrackets1);
    printf("\nOccurence of character } : %d ", Cbrackets2);
    printf("\nAverage number of spaces and tabulations: %2.f", avgTAS);
    printf("\nPercentage of comment text in the file: %2.f%%", commAVG);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

My view is that the for loop goes through the whole array in which the text is stored. If it meets a specific set of characters (/* or //) it starts adding 1 to an int. While adding if it finds spaces in between, it subtracts 1. If it meets another specific character or set of characters (/* or \n) it stops adding and the for loop takes over and finishes searching through the whole array. The problem is that it's calculating something else and I can't figure out the flaw in my method. Thanks !

Comment: Can you give some numbers how far your actual result is from the expected? Also please explain how accurate and how complete your result should be (there are some nasty ways of commenting in C/C++)

Comment: Why do you not want spaces in the comments counted?

Comment: "The problem is that it's calculating something else" is too vague to be a problem.. You should try to narrow it down first..

Comment: Do you get strange results only for files with multiline comments? (Which your code does not handle.)

Comment: Every line in the text that I use starts with // but in the end I get that 400% of the whole text is comments. It should be something between 0% and 100%. 
Not counting the spaces is just required by my teacher. I disagree with her on that part though.

Comment: `char* myString = "This is a string /* with what looks like a comment */ in it";`

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output several messages, including that the `gets()` function is depreciated .  Actually `gets()` should never be used.  Suggest `fgets()`.

Comment: However, your application should be written to 'tokenize' to code perhaps via a 'state' machine, where the states could be: 1) not in a comment and 2) in a comment.  The 'not in a comment' would count nothing, and be looking for the beginning of a comment.  The 'in a comment' would count all non spaces while looking for the end of the comment.   However, macros (and other things) can place comments in the code that are VERY difficult to accurately  count

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) do not call functions that are not part of the standard C library AND are not fully listed in the code.  For instance: `_getche()`

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: putting large arrays on the stack is not a good idea, Suggest using a `malloc()` or placing the array in the file global space.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. IE. 75, 2000, 10000.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those numbers meaningful naes, then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: The input file could easily be longer than 10000 characters.  The loop that is reading the input file into `str[]` would then overflow the input buffer resulting in undefined behavior and leading to a seg fault event.

Comment: when inputting the characters from the input file, there is no need to keep more than the current char and an indication of 'in/not ina literal, in/not in a comment, and the kind of comment. `/*` or `//` and an indication of a possible comment start or possible comment end when the prior character was a `*` or `/`.  The posted code makes no distinguishment for any of the possible states of the input stream.

Comment: the calculation of the variable: `commAVG` uses all integer math, so will (almsot) always be incorrect.   The calculation of `avgTAS` has a 50percent chance of giving a value that is missing the fraction because it uses all integer math.

Comment: the returned value from a call to `fgetc()` is an `int`, not a `char`, so this line: `char ch, file_name[75];`  should be `int ch; char file_name[75];`

Comment: this line: `fp = fopen(file_name, "a");` is opening the file for `append`, not for `read`.  which means the comment is wrong as the file is actually being written to.  Question: why clutter the code with appending some random sentence onto the end of the file that will be read?

Answer (score 1):

Lets do a little play through... (the thing you should do with your debugger)

```
for (k = 0; k < fsize; k++) {
    if (str[k] == '/' && str[k + 1] == '*') {
        while (str[k] != '*' && str[k + 1] != '/') {
            commNum1++;
            if (str[k] == ' ') {
                commNum1--;
            }
            //              printf("commNum1 = %d\n",commNum1);                 //just to test if my calculations are correct
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Consider the text `"/* abc */"`

```
if (str[0] == '/' && str[1] == '*') // true
while (str[0] != '*' && str[1] != '/') // true
commNum1++;
k++;
while (str[1] != '*' && str[2] != '/') // false, cause str[1] == '*'
```

End of story.

You should try to first increment k above the comment start and then change the `while` condition

```
while (str[k] != '*' || str[k + 1] != '/') // instead of &&
```

Also, in loops where you use look-ahead, adjust your bounds

```
for (k = 0; k < (fsize - 1); k++) // instead of k < fsize
```

Maybe you have more errors, but this is the obvious one.

**Edit:**

Since you mentioned the 400% problem:

You potentially add the same comment for both, `commNum1` and `commNum2`, if the comment is formed like `//* comment text` or `/*// comment text */`

Also, your inner while loops don't check for `k < fsize`, which means that the check will reach beyond the end of array for the last line in file. There you get undefined behavior, potentially counting after-end-of-file-comments until 400% are reached.

Things I'm not going to address further:

```
/\
* comment starts here, cause \ is preprocessor line removal which merges the two lines into a /*
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean that while reading the comment, if it reaches * or / it'll stop? What if the comment is something like this: /*random and/or random*/ If so while counting wouldn't it stop between "and" and "or" ?

Comment: @gEshAdve No, you reversed the condition. As you have it now, it would stop if `'*'` OR `'/'` is found, because you continue as long as `'*'` AND `'/'` is NOT found.

Comment: @gEshAdve Added an edit about your while loops going out of bounds.